# Special character drawing using CCLabelTTF is broken in some android phone

Tags: encoding, cocos2d-x

This is code(Using Cocos2d-x),

```
CCLabelTTF *labelLevel = CCLabelTTF::create("Hello ▇ ⓫ ₩ ⅀", "Arial", 15);
labelLevel->setPosition(ccp(0, 0));
labelLevel->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0, 1));
this->addChild(labelLevel);
```

in iOS phone, it works well.
But, in some android phone (ex, Nexus 1),
the special character(.▇ ⓫ ₩ ⅀) doesn't displayed well, skipped(blank) or just box.

My IDE is Xcode and the file encoding type is utf-8.

Comment: if it only happens to `some` android devices, I guess you can't do much to fix it. The only thing you could do is to avoid those characters.

Comment: agree with above. If you insist to try more, try another font.

Comment: Change another font may help.

Comment: some font crashed with special character in some android phone.

Comment: and 'Arial' didn't crashed, just blanked or displayed box.

Comment: can not avoid special characters. because user nick names have special characters. the name list get from server.